# Is it possible to remove # from url?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I want to scroll down to the product section on my page.
I use www.example.com/#product and it works correctly scrolled down to the product section.
If I use js it will scroll down to the product section too, but url is not included /product.

Can I scroll down to the product section without # like example.com/product?

[.htaccess image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjvjx.png)

[link image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAYIw.png)

Comment: Read about URL Rewriting!

Comment: use `www.example.com/#product` and remove `#` with javascript `window.location.hash = '';`

Comment: I've tried to rewrite url but it's not working

Answer (score -1):

In javascript

```
const getURLParamValue = (query) => {
    let t = document.URL,
        a = query,
        params = i = j = k = null,
        arr = [];
    params = t.split('?')[1].split('&');
    l = params.length;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        k = params[i].split('=');
        arr[k[0]] = k[1].replace('#','');
    }
    return arr[a];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using this?

```
if(section === 'products'){
    $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $("#products").offset().top
    }, 500);
}
```